# Rails create multiple records at once from nested attributes on a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I have model PurchaseOrder and PurchaseOrderList. When I create a purchase order it updates both tables purchase_orders and purchase_order_lists with a nested form.

Now I want to be able to add a button update stock on purchase_orders/show. When I click this button a new record will be created on table stockdiaries with same products, units and prices as on the purchase order.

The logic is that first I create a purchase order and then I click the button to update stock when goods are received.

The best I came up with is to create this method on PurchaseOrders controller:

```
 def update_stock
   @purchase_order_list = PurchaseOrderList.where(PURCHASE_ORDER: params[:ID])
   @stockdiary = Stockdiary.create(PRODUCT: @purchase_order_list.PRODUCT, UNITS: @purchase_order_list.UNITS, PRICEBUY: @purchase_order_list.PRICEBUY)
   flash[:notice] = "Stock updated successfully."
   redirect_to(:action => 'show', :ID => @purchase_order.ID)
 end
```

and in my purchase_orders/show:

```
<%= link_to "Update Stock", { controller: :purchase_orders, action: :update_stock, ID: @purchase_order.ID} %>
```

but it raises error

```
undefined method `PRODUCT' for
#<PurchaseOrderList::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f1efeff4898>
```

But there is a column PRODUCT on purchase_order_lists table.

Note that I included in the method only columns that are common to purchase_order_lists and stockdiaries as others (as id or status) are not concerned on this question. Columns names are capital as I'm building the app on existing db.

What is the correct way to create a stockdiary from a purchase order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Rails is returning an an **ActiveRecord Relation** from this query:

```
@purchase_order_list = PurchaseOrderList.where(PURCHASE_ORDER: params[:ID])
```

This is because you used `where`, so ActiveRecord returns a relation that could potentially have multiple records in it. If you only want one record, or even if you know that there will only be one record then you should use `find_by`

So you can either do:

```
# change where to find_by
@purchase_order_list = PurchaseOrderList.find_by(PURCHASE_ORDER: params[:ID])
# and then this will work
@stockdiary = Stockdiary.create(PRODUCT: @purchase_order_list.PRODUCT, UNITS: @purchase_order_list.UNITS, PRICEBUY: @purchase_order_list.PRICEBUY)
```

**OR... If you want `where` or there might be multiple records, then you can loop:**

```
@purchase_order_list = PurchaseOrderList.where(PURCHASE_ORDER: params[:ID])
# and then loop through you potentially multiple records in @purchase_order_list
@purchase_order_list.each do |po|
  @stockdiary = Stockdiary.create(PRODUCT: po.PRODUCT, UNITS: po.UNITS, PRICEBUY: po.PRICEBUY)
end
```

or use `first`:

```
@stockdiary = Stockdiary.create(PRODUCT: @purchase_order_list.first.PRODUCT, UNITS: @purchase_order_list.first.UNITS, PRICEBUY: @purchase_order_list.first.PRICEBUY)
```

<strike>Usually this means you didn't place [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for) in the PurchaseOrder model.</strike>

<strike>**PurchaseOrder**</strike>

```
class PurchaseOrder
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :purchase_order_list
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I already placed that in my model. I can create purchase orders with a nested form and it creates records correctly on purchase_order_lists table. That wouldn't work if I hadn't.

Comment: And anyway as far as i know the correct syntax is` accepts_nested_attributes_for :purchase_order_lists` (plural)

Comment: ok, yea. I had a typo and I didn't read your question very carefully. Now I get it. Let me look and see. I know I've had that error in a similar case before

Comment: ok, @Catmal updated. Change `where` to `find_by` if you only want one record, or if you want multiple records then you should loop through `@purchase_order_list` and create one `Stockdiary` for each, depending on your requirements

Comment: Yes that was it thanks a lot. I need to loop tho (I want to create a stockdiary for each purchase_order_list). But I'm not sure about the syntax. Could you give me an example if it's not too bother?

Comment: ok @Catmal I just updated my answer with a loop: `@purchase_order_list.each{ |po|
  @stockdiary = Stockdiary.create(PRODUCT: po.PRODUCT, UNITS: po.UNITS, PRICEBUY: po.PRICEBUY) }`